# Laravel delete multiple checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I'm new to deleting multiple checkboxes so i need a little help. I've been searching the web for like hours but i can't fix my problem.

I have a todo list and there are some todo's showing from the database on my webpage.How can i delete all selected checkboxes in one click?

I'm using **Laravel 5.4**

**ToDoController:**

```
public function destroy()
   {
    $checked = Request::input('checked')['checked'];
    $checked->delete();
   }
```

**Blade:**

```
@foreach ($todo as $todoresult)

            <form method="get" action="/todo/destroy/">

          <div class="checkbox">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$todoresult->id}}" name="checked[]">{{$todoresult->todoinfo}}</label><br />

          </div> 

            @endforeach

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Verwerken</button>

            </form>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/todo/destroy/', 'ToDoController@destroy');
```

How would i do this? And how would my routing be like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following would probably work:

```
public function destroy() {
   $checked = Request::input('checked',[]);
   foreach ($checked as $id) {
        Todo::where("id",$id)->delete(); //Assuming you have a Todo model. 
   }
   //Or as @Alex suggested 
   Todo::whereIn($checked)->delete();
}
```

Comment: `Todo::whereIn('id', $checked)->delete()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When i use this i get this in the url: /todo/destroy?checked%5B%5D=26&checked%5B%5D=27. 26 and 27 are the correct ID. But how can i route this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to loop query.
You can use WhereIn to delete multiple ids

```
   public function destroy() {
       $checked = Request::input('checked',[]);
      Todo::whereIn("id",$checked)->delete(); 

}
```